# Refused to display <Facebook URL> in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I try to load basic example for facebook page button, but every time my app give me this error in the console `Refused to display <Facebook URL> in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.`

I create a new file Facebook.js with code:

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { FacebookProvider, Like } from 'react-facebook';

export default class Facebook extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <FacebookProvider appId="103937101364181">
        <Like href="https://www.facebook.com" colorScheme="dark" showFaces share />
      </FacebookProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

In the Home.js file I import this line:

```
import Facebook from '../Facebook';
```

In render I use this tag:

```
<Facebook></Facebook>
```

The component not load on the page and I see error in the console log.

Can I get some example how to fix that ?

Comment: May be you need to add your website domain to white-list in facebook developer admin.

Comment: Can you tell me how, please.. ?

Comment: Did you have a look to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7CNpLgwa0-c)? It's indeed apparently needed to do something on facebook dev site